# Glyphicons inside labels are cut off in mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a code like this:

```
<span class="label label-info">
    327<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
</span>
```

On desktop view I see all right, but on mobile I see half icon, how i fix it?

Comment: We'll probably need a demo. Not much to go on here, and it seems fine. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rtaby7fm/

Comment: ... or more code. What's around this?

Comment: I put here http://jsfiddle.net/3mhfub0z/ more code @isherwood

Comment: They don't seem to be cut off there, either.

Comment: It's true! on jsfiddle they aren't cutted off, but on my device (moto G) on my site they're cutted off, can you check it http://idraulica.diegodalbosco.eu/ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some time I found the problem, before I was using an Alias Web for my site so all the page was inside an , now i change the type of record in 'A' and the problem is fixed. (also the navbar wasn't displayed right on mobile)